# Bootstrap how to make a single line element in navbar take up the full height when other elements are 2 lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the screen resizes, the longer elements in my navbar switch to two lines to take up less space. This makes the navbar taller. When I hover over a single line element it only highlights the original single line height, similar to the navbar in [asti.ie](http://www.asti.ie). How do I get it to highlight the full height of the navbar? And also to center the text vertically if possible. Thanks

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0dad1czz/1/

The result screen needs to be wide enough for the navbar to show. Also, I know the text overflows when the screen is too thin, that's no problem, I'll fix it later.

HTML:

```
<div id="topnav" class="container hidden-xs">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" style="padding: 0;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LEADERSHIP DEVELOPMENT</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="row border-between" style="width: 600px;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="nav-dropdown-info">
                                            <img src="images/african-union-small.png">
                                            <img src="images/ForminFinland_logo.png">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et suscipit neque. Curabitur consectetur ligula neque, ut accumsan lacus vestibulum id. Donec sollicitudin dignissim laoreet.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="col-sm-6">
                                        <li><a href="#">GOVERNMENT LEADERSHIP</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">EDUCATION LEADERSHIP</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">TEACHING LEADERSHIP</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">YOUTH LEADERSHIP</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY LEADERSHIP</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">OUR WORK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COUNTRIES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PARTNERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MEDIA & INFO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
@import "colours";

#topnav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

#topnav .navbar {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    .nav {
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        /*display: table;*/
        li {
            width: 14.2857142857%;
            margin: auto;
            /*display: table-cell;*/
            a {
                text-align: center;
                &:hover {
                    background-color: $blue;
                    color: #fff;
                }
            }
        }

        .dropdown-menu {
            .nav-dropdown-info {
                padding: 15px 15px 25px 15px;
                img {
                    padding-left: 9px;
                    padding-right: 9px;
                }
                p {
                    padding-top: 30px;
                }
            }
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }
            li {
                width: auto;
            }
            li a {
                display: block;
                color: $black;
                text-align: left;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 10px 25px;
                &:hover {
                    background-color: $blue;
                    color: #fff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#topnav .navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open.active > a:hover, #topnav .navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open > a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: $blue;
}

#topnav .navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 0) {
  #topnav .navbar-toggle {
    display: block; /* force showing the toggle */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #topnav .navbar {
    right: auto;
    background: none;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Sounds like a display issue in css.

Comment: Done. I used sass, I can add the compiled css if you want

Comment: Post a fiddle, it would be easy to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a height and a line-height on the li elements. And add display inline-block and vertical align middle to the a elements in this li. I would suggest to add the hover animation (background change) to the li instead of the a and center align the text.

```
#topnav .navbar .nav li {
  width: 14.2857142857%;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 70px;              /* added */
  height: 70px;                   /* added */
  text-align: center;             /* added */
}
#topnav .navbar .nav li a {
  display: inline-block;          /* added */
  vertical-align: middle;         /* added */
}
#topnav .navbar .nav li:hover a,  /* added */
#topnav .navbar .nav li:hover {   /* added */
  background-color: #0097e6;      /* added */
  color: #fff;                    /* added */
}
```

For a full preview:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGaJpE